# MongoDB - how to handle write failures during primary re-election with Spring?

Tags: spring, mongodb, database-replication, spring-data-mongodb

I configured my MongoDB replica set with Spring, and I'm trying to test the auto-failover.
I know that if the primary goes down, it takes a few seconds for a new primary to be elected, so in that time period, all writes will fail.

I have a test application that writes to the db every 1 sec, and when I take down the primary, I get a java.io.IOException (because there's no primary to write to). If I restart my application the writes are executed without a problem to the new primary.

I thought that the MongoDB Java driver can handle those cases using retries (was I wrong?), but I was unable to configure Spring to do that, so I'd appriciate some help. :)

My configuration is like so:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017">
    <mongo:options
        connections-per-host="8"
        threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
        connect-timeout="1000"
        max-wait-time="1500"
        auto-connect-retry="true"
        socket-keep-alive="true"
        socket-timeout="1500"
        slave-ok="true"
        write-number="1"
        write-timeout="0"
        write-fsync="true"/>
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:repositories base-package="my.repositories" />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="my_db" mongo-ref="mongo" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include a stack trace? Generally, the thing to consider is that a failure may or may not be persistent. It may or may not have reached a secondary. These require custom application logic to work out how to deal with, for example, retry. If the update is ono-idempotent (e.g. an $inc) you may not want it to retry.

Comment: So basically there's no driver/OOTB solution and we need to implement it ourselves, right? Do you maybe have an example of such a mechanism?
We're trying to find a general solution to this problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an initial stab at a spring aop/spring retry custom RetryPolicy for generic retry in various circumstances.
This is quite brittle (as it uses exception messages, etc which are subject to change). I would recommend robust testing, and definitely repeating on change of MongoDB and/or java driver version.

Firstly, maven dependancies used:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Second, a custom *org.springframework.retry.RetryPolicy*

```
import org.springframework.retry.RetryContext;
import org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CustomMongoDBRetryPolicy extends SimpleRetryPolicy {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomMongoDBRetryPolicy.class.getName());
    public CustomMongoDBRetryPolicy(int maxAttempts) {
        super(maxAttempts, createRetryableExceptions(), true);
    }

    private static Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> createRetryableExceptions() {
        HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> classBooleanHashMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>();
        classBooleanHashMap.put(org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException.class, true);
        classBooleanHashMap.put(org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException.class, true);
        classBooleanHashMap.put(com.mongodb.MongoException.class, true);
        classBooleanHashMap.put(java.net.ConnectException.class, true);
        return classBooleanHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRetry(RetryContext context) {
        boolean retry = super.canRetry(context);
        if (retry) {
            @SuppressWarnings("ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
            Throwable lastThrowable = context.getLastThrowable();
            if (lastThrowable != null) {
                String message = lastThrowable.getMessage();
                Throwable cause = lastThrowable.getCause();
                if (message != null) {
                    if (message.startsWith("No replica set members available in")) {
                        logger.info("Retrying because no replica set members available. "+message);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (message.startsWith("not talking to master and retries used up")) {
                        logger.info("Retrying because no master. "+message);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (message.startsWith("can't find a master")) {
                        logger.info("Retrying because no master. "+message);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (message.matches("Read operation to server [^\\s]* failed on database .*")) {
                        logger.info("Retrying because read operation failed. "+message);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (cause != null) {
                    String causeMessage = cause.getMessage();
                    if (causeMessage != null) {
                        if (causeMessage.startsWith("Connection refused")) {
                            logger.info("Retrying because connection not available. "+causeMessage+"("+message+")");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                logger.info("Not retrying. "+message+" "+lastThrowable.getClass().getName());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return retry;
    }
}
```

Finally, tie into Dao using spring AOP

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="false">
    <aop:pointcut id="retry"
                  expression="execution(* IMyDao.count(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="retry2"
                  expression="execution(* IMyDao.insert(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="retry"
                 advice-ref="retryAdvice" order="-1"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="retry2"
                 advice-ref="retryAdvice" order="-1"/>
</aop:config>
```

The following combines *org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy*, to delay retries, *org.springframework.retry.policy.TimeoutRetryPolicy*, to limit retry time and the *CustomMongoDBRetryPolicy*, which retries what seems to be retry-able...

```
<bean id="retryAdvice"
      class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor">
    <property name="retryOperations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.CompositeRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="optimistic" value="false"/>
                    <property name="policies">
                        <set>
                            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.TimeoutRetryPolicy">
                                <property name="timeout" value="20000"/>
                            </bean>
                            <bean class="CustomMongoDBRetryPolicy">
                                <constructor-arg value="100"/>
                            </bean>
                        </set>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="listeners">
                <set>
                    <bean class="MyRetryListener"/>
                </set>
            </property>
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="500"/>
                    <property name="maxInterval" value="8000"/>
                    <property name="multiplier" value="1.5"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Ive tested this with various scenarios, and it seem to be handling most pretty well. But whether it will work for a particular application, needs to be answered on a case by case basis.

- Initial replicaset start - regular autoreconnect handles before the servers are listening, this handles prior to primary election - all invisible to the application (bar a long lag)
- Killing the primary - write operation in progress fails to the application, subsequent retry
- Stepping down the primary, shutting down the primary - as killing the primary.
- Full replicaset restart (if fast enough)

Hope this helps

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your help! :) We'll try to implement something similar...

Comment: If a framework leads you into writing this, well... was it a gain?

Answer (score -1):

you set socket-timeout="1500". you should not set any socket timeout. Defaults to 0 (infinite time).

Comment: Hi, I removed the socket-timeout but I still get an java.io.IOException when the primary goes down...

Comment: @Ayelet ok, not socket-timeout, but connect-timeout. It works to me :)